# Automapper ProjectTo not working when used with custom mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2, automapper-7

I am using asp.net core 2.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(2.2.4), Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos(2.2.4), AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection(7.0.0)

Here goes my code:

**MappingProfile.cs**

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Languages, LanguageDTO>();        
        CreateMap<Countries, CountryDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Uuid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CountryId)).ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DisplayName)).ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayNameShort, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Helper.ReplaceChars(src.DisplayName))).ForMember(dest => dest.Path, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Helper.ReplaceChars(src.DisplayName)));
    }
}
```

**ServiceClass.cs**

```
countries = await _mapper.ProjectTo<CountryDTO>(_dbContext.Countries.Where(cc => cc.IsPublished.Equals(true) && cc.LanguageId.Equals(dftLanguageId))).ToListAsync();
```

**Models**

```
public class Countries
{
    public string id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CountryId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? SVGImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? PNGImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsPublished
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CreatedBy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CreatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string UpdatedBy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string UpdatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? CountryContentId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? LanguageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DisplayNameShort
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class CountryResult
{
    public CountryResult()
    {
        Countries = new List<CountryDTO>();
    }

    public List<CountryDTO> Countries
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class CountryDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("pngimagePath")]
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string PNGImagePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [JsonProperty("svgimagePath")]
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string SVGImagePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string DisplayNameShort
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string ProviderName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string ProviderTerms
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    public int Uuid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string Path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    = "";
    public bool CompleteResponse
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here I am seeing that all values are not getting mapped. For example Name is set to empty string and CompleteResponse set to false.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Comment: Could you share the definition of the relevant models in order to reproduce your problem, share?

Comment: @XueliChen - Any help on this issue is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ProjectTo` as follows :

```
var countries = _dbContext.Countries
            .Where(cc => cc.IsPublished.Equals(true) && cc.LanguageId.Equals(dftLanguageId))
            .ProjectTo<CountryDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
```

Note : Unless the name of  properties between the source and the destination are same, you need to use `ForMember()` to map the properties one-to-one. Otherwise the value are not getting mapped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :). It helped to fix the issue.